# Quartus II - Can I include other files into a *.qsf file?

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus-ii, quartus, xdc, tcl

An Altera Quartus II project consists of one *.qpf and one or more *.qsf files. The qsf seems to be a TCL script like other EDA related settings and config files (e.g. xdc, sdc, ...).

**Is is possible to include other TCL scripts into the qsf?**

I don't like the idea of storing all design settings in one file (source files, pin assignments, ...). Like in ISE or Vivado, I would like to store e.g. pin assignments in seperate files and included them.

**Excurse ISE:**

ISE uses UCF files to store constraints for pins, placement and timings. It's possible to add multiple ucf files to one project. E.g. a `GPIO.LED.ucf` or a `Clock.SystemClock.ucf`.

**Excurse Vivado :**

Vivado stores constraints in xdc files (Xilinx Design Constraints - a Xilinx extended version of SDC files - Synopsys Design Constraints). XDC/SDC files are TCL scripts. Quartus also uses SDC files.

Comment: Pin assignments can be in a separate TCL file.

Comment: @LeonHeller Yes, but how I include this file?

Comment: Select Files in the Project Navigator and right click on Files. You can then add the TCL file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested with Quartus II 15.0**

Its possible to add lines like these to the *.qsf file:

```
set LoadPinConstraints 1
source ../../constraints/DE4/GPIO.Button.Reset.sdc
source ../../constraints/DE4/GPIO.Buttons.sdc
source ../../constraints/DE4/GPIO.SlideSwitches.sdc
source ../../constraints/DE4/GPIO.LEDs.sdc
```

(These *.sdc files include pin assignments, I/O settings (voltage, standard, ...) and pin timings.)

**But**, Quartus will report a bad formatted *.qsf file with unsupported commands. After that, Quartus inlines all external pin assignments into the *.qsf file.

So yes it's possible, but the goal of modularization is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands in the qsf file -
    set_global_assignment -name PRE_FLOW_SCRIPT_FILE quartus_sh:script_file.tcl

For an example checkout [this page](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Tcl_Scripts_for_Automatic_Build_Identification) - The example script file is in the zip archive on that page.

Answer (score 1):

In Quartus Prime ver. 18.1 it is possible to do:

```
set_global_assignment -name SOURCE_TCL_SCRIPT_FILE pinout.tcl
```